# How to resolve ERROR: null root node returned by UiTestAutomationBridge error

Tags: python, appium, android-uiautomator

I am trying to locate "call accept" and "call reject" elements on Samsung S6 edge device in case of an incoming or outgoing call.

However, I'm getting the error:

`root node returned by UiTestAutomationBridge error`

Below is my code

```
from subprocess import call
def host_exec():
    try:
        call(["adb", "shell", "uiautomator", "dump", "/sdcard/dump.xml"])
    except RuntimeError:
        print >>sys.stderr

dq = host_exec()
```

I am using:

- python 2.7
- android studio 2.1.1
- appium 1.6.5

Answer (score 3):

Its a known bug that can usually be solved by simple rebooting the Device

Comment: No Problem ^^! Its a known bug that can mostly be solved by simple rebooting the Device

Comment: can you provide a reference for the bug?